# Is there an R function to add columns by multipling value of an other column?

Tags: r, dataframe, market-basket-analysis

I want to do an association analysis, but need to bring my data frame into the right format, which only shows transactions. 1) How can I multiply my "Sub Category" column by the amount of "Quantity" column?

2) How can I group the Transactions by Order-ID?

I have this df:

```
 `Order ID`        `Sub-Category` `Quantity`
  <chr>              <chr>             <dbl>

1 CA-2017-152156    Bookcases             2

2 CA-2017-152156    Chairs                3

3 CA-2017-138688    Labels                2
```

1) I want this:

```
  `Order ID`     `Sub-Category` `Sub-Category2`   `Sub-Category3`
  <chr>          <chr>             <chr>           <chr>

1 CA-2017-152156 Bookcases        Bookcases         NULL

2 CA-2017-152156 Chairs             Chairs          Chairs

3 CA-2017-138688 Labels            Labels           NULL
```

(After that I want to combine same Order IDs. E.g. row 1 and 2. Do you have a hint for that?)
Thank you!

Comment: You say you *want to combine same Order IDs*. What is the expected output of 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answers to point 1).

```
Max <- max(df1$Quantity)
res <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i){
  c(rep(as.character(df1[i, 2]), df1[i, 3]), rep(NA, Max - df1[i, 3]))
})
res <- cbind(df1[1], do.call(rbind, res))
names(res)[-1] <- paste0(names(df1)[2], names(res)[-1])

res
#        Order ID Sub-Category1 Sub-Category2 Sub-Category3
#1 CA-2017-152156     Bookcases     Bookcases          <NA>
#2 CA-2017-152156        Chairs        Chairs        Chairs
#3 CA-2017-138688        Labels        Labels          <NA>
```

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(`Order ID` = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), 
.Label = c("CA-2017-138688", "CA-2017-152156"), 
class = "factor"), `Sub-Category` = structure(1:3, 
.Label = c("Bookcases", "Chairs", "Labels"), class = 
"factor"), Quantity = c(2L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer question 1) using `tidyverse`, one way is to create a new column `rep`eat every `Sub-Category` `Quantity` number of times and store it as one string in a comma-separated format and then `separate` them into `n` columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

n <- max(df$Quantity)

df1 <- df %>%
         mutate(new = map2_chr(`Sub-Category`, Quantity, ~paste(rep(.x, .y), collapse = ","))) %>%
         separate(new, paste("Sub-Category", seq_len(n))) %>%
         select(-`Sub-Category`)

df1

#       Order ID  Quantity Sub-Category 1 Sub-Category 2 Sub-Category 3
#1 CA-2017-152156        2      Bookcases      Bookcases           <NA>
#2 CA-2017-152156        3         Chairs         Chairs         Chairs
#3 CA-2017-138688        2         Labels         Labels           <NA>
```

As far as question 2) is concerned I am not 100% clear what you are looking for (as there is no expected output) but I think you are looking to `group_by` `Order ID` and collapse categories into one row for each group?

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(`Order ID`) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Sub")), list(~paste(na.omit(.), collapse = ",")))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  `Order ID`   `Sub-Category 1` `Sub-Category 2` `Sub-Category 3`
#  <fct>          <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
#1 CA-2017-138688 Labels           Labels           ""              
#2 CA-2017-152156 Bookcases,Chairs Bookcases,Chairs Chairs
```